# string termination problem

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to run this script i get error in IE:

```
Unterminated string constant


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var designDocumen;
        var designEditor;

        Initialize();
       function Initialize() {     
           designEditor = $get('myframe');

            designDocument = this.designEditor.contentWindow.document;            

            var outerHTML =
            "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>" +
            "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<title>Design Editor Frame</title>" +
            "<style type='text/css'>" +
            "body {background-color:Green;}"+
            "</style>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body></body>" +
            "</html>";                      

           designDocument.open("text/html", "replace");
           designDocument.write(outerHTML);
           designDocument.close();               
        }           


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>      

     <iframe id="myframe" height="500px" width="500px">
     </iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I solve this? How to correct this string?

**UPDATE:**
The problem is with the line:

> `"<title>Design Editor Frame</title>"`

if i remove it, it works!

Comment: He gets "Unterminated string constant", per the first line of the code block.

Comment: You forgot to terminate your string constant.

Comment: And who up-voted this ridiculous question?  This is not useful to anybody.

Comment: @Josh Stodola if it's ridiculous, don't reply at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four things;

1. you declare `designDocumen` but use `designDocument` later
2. you need to define the function `Initialize()` before you call it
3. you need this script to be place at the bottom of your `body` element otherwise the `iframe` will not be available.
4. you have no definition for `$get` so you will need to include the correct script library to use this method.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `+` missing after `"body {background-color:Green;}"`.

Comment: I still get this error. (my original code has +, it was copy&paste problem )

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `+` after this line `"body {background-color:Green;}"`.

Comment: I still get this error. (my original code has +, it was copy&paste problem )